# CSS animations: svg rotating and transform applied on hover: the rotation angle resets on hover

Tags: css, animation, rotation, transform

I have an SVG which represent a cannon that is constantly rotating (from -5 deg to -80deg), and I want it to stop rotating on hover and apply a transform (scale - it should look like it's firing in a cartoonish way). Everything works but the rotation angle is reset to the original value: I want it to retain the angle it has when you hover it. Thanks for any hint.

```
.cannon {

    bottom: 60px;

    display: block;

    left: 2%;

    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;

    animation: cannon-change-pitch;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    transform-origin: 35% 80%;
}

.cannon:hover {

    animation: cannon-fire;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-duration: 30ms;
    animation-iteration-count: 2;
}

@keyframes cannon-change-pitch {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(-5deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(-80deg);
    }
}

@keyframes cannon-fire {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.9);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
}
```

Comment: move the rotation to a parent element so it keep working

Comment: the parent element is currently body, should I put the cannon in a div and rotate the div?

Comment: yes, try it, it should work

Comment: it worked! thanks!